# How to compare two table columns in sql server using c#

Tags: c#, sql

I want to compare two different table columns (ID) if the both id's are same i want to insert Location Name Having in the first table to second table

```
Table 1
-------
    Id   Name
    ---------
    1    Hyd
    2    Banglore
    ---------

Table 2
-------
    Id Name
    -------
    1 
    2
```

From the first table id and second table id if both are equal i want to insert name column in the second column which existed in the same id row  Using C# Help me

Comment: Where are you stuck?  You can compare values with the equality operator (`==`), you can conditionally run code based on that comparison with a conditional block `if (someCondition) { ... }`, you can connect to the database in lots of different ways.  What have you tried and what isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

Well without a lot of info here goes.

This is Assuming that when you say c# you actually mean C# to SQL.

so in SQL do something like this

```
UPDATE Table2
SET Table2.Name = Table1.name
FROM Table1
WHERE Table2.ID = table1.ID
```

make this a stored procedure, then use c# to call run the procedure.

again this is just an example and is based on the assumption that you actually want this done in SQL and use c# to run it

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
create table #testsource
(ID int,city nvarchar(200))

insert into #testsource (ID,city)
values(1,'mumbai'),
(2,'Pune')

select *from #testsource

create table #testdestination
(ID int,city nvarchar(200))

//insert rows in table
insert into #testdestination (ID,city) values(1,''),(2,''),(3,'')

//select rows from table
select *from #testdestination

//get the values from Source table and update to Destination table
update #testdestination set city=s.city 
from #testsource s 
where s.ID=#testdestination.ID

select *from #testdestination

drop table #testsource
drop table #testdestination
```

**Results:**
[image]

Assuming your two table names with **'Table1'** & '**Table2**'

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_UpdateDestinationTable]
AS
BEGIN
UPDATE Table2
SET Table2.Name = t1.name
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE Table2.ID = t1.ID
```

**NOTE:** This is a sample used with `Temporay` `Table` plelase **do not use "as is"**. make changes according to your needs.